# Comparison without "Gerund"

Tags: prepositions

I had face this situation that I want to use both word in simple form with *to* instead of a gerund.

Original sentence:

> **Taking** the oral examination is usually harder than **writing** the dissertation.

Except sentence:

> **To take** the oral examination is usually harder than **to write** the dissertation.

I asked from my teacher and he replied that we should change the structure.

Comment: What part is causing you trouble?

Comment: The OP seems to be asking about the use of "writing" and "to write" in the original sentence. Soheil Aghayanim, the sentence is a comparison and thus should have a parallel structure, thus "Taking the oral examination is usually harder than writing the dissertation." is correct and "To take the oral examination is usually harder than to write the dissertation." is acceptable. However, as you are talking about actions, then the "-ing" form is preferable.

Comment: @KillingTime I want to have both verb in form of "to" + verb, but I don't know how to change it from original from with out error.

Comment: @Greybeard but harder is comparison and then is preposition so after that I should use ing form of verb, right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can gerund and infinitive forms be interchangeable when functioning as subject of a sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/416319/can-gerund-and-infinitive-forms-be-interchangeable-when-functioning-as-subject-o)

Comment: @Soheil: Although that is usual, it is not a "rule." (i) "To plant the crop is easier than to harvest it." - (ii) "To plant the crop is easier than harvesting it." - (iii) "Planting the crop is easier than harvesting it." - (iii) "To plant the crop is easier than to harvest it." are all correct. However, it is usual to use the same form of the verb in both parts, and the continuous in both is the commonest.

Comment: @Greybeard Thanks for helping but (ii) is not correct according to parallel Grammer. Am I right? Or native people say that too?

Comment: @Greybeard (iv) 'Planting the crop is easier than to harvest it' sounds unidiomatic,  almost outlandish, to my ears (and if correct that would make it, according to Orwell, unacceptable).

Comment: All you have to do is move the core verb *is*: "It is easier to plant the crop than to harvest it."

Comment: @Soheil - Parallel grammar is a recommendation and it often improves writing, but that doesn't mean all unparallel grammar is somehow "incorrect."